# can you return implicit type from a method?

Tags: c#-4.0, types, implicit

Can you do something like this in C#

```
var GetSomething()
{
    var x = new { a = "b", i = 1 };
    return x;
}
```

Or maybe is there any alternative that I can do? About having a type for the return yes, I know about that. I was looking for something more generic :D

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you want to do such a thing as likely you will get better advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to return anonymous type. I returned it as an object and then cast it. Thanks for anyone who answered :D

```
object GetSomething()
{
    var x = new { a = "b", i = 1 };
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`var` is syntactic sugar - it is not a lack of type. The type is determined in compile time.

It can only be used inside methods.

Perhaps you are looking to use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) instead.

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.

Also see [Using Type dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

```
dynamic GetSomething()
{
    dynamic x = new { a = "b", i = 1 };
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = GetSomething();

static   Object  GetSomething()
{
    var x = new { a = "b", i = 1 };
    return (Object)x;
}
```

Anonymous types can be returned from methods but must be cast to object, which defeats the purpose of strong typing.

Comment: Would probably be useful to add how (or if) the member fields of the original anonymous type can be recovered by casting back?